# Show that the built set $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = 1 \}$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I see that the set $\{ x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = 1 \}$ is bounded, because given any $y$ there are exactly two $x$ such that $x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = 1$ and so is the case where $x$ is given.

But I do not see how to show the set is closed, so that it is indeed compact.

Comment: If $(x_n,y_n)\to(x,y)$ and $x_n^2+x_ny_n+y_n^2=1$ then taking limits $x^2+xy+y^2=1$.

Comment: The set is the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ by the continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2-1$.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the trouble to write! I see. Would you write an answer so that I can accept it and then other viewers can also share the knowledge?

Comment: Your argument that it is bounded doesn't really work.  Yes for each $y$ there are two $x$'s, but that doesn't mean it is bounded, why can't $y$ be arbitrarily large?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, thanks! Would you write up an answer?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2=2$, therefore $x^2+y^2\leq2$.

Comment: Clever! Yes. Then I know the whole things.

Comment: @ABC: More like irrelevant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for formal answer:

**Boundedness:** The points in the set satisfy $x^2+xy+y^2=1$. Then $x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2=2$, from where $x^2+y^2\leq2$. This means that its points are always at distance $\leq \sqrt{2}$ from the origin.

**Closedness:** If $(x_n,y_n)\to(x,y)$ such that $x_n^2+x_ny_n+y_n^2=1$ then taking limits on both sides we get $x^2+xy+y^2=1$. This means that the limit point is also in the set.

... and many other ways ...

Comment: Sorry I fail to see why every point in the set is an accumulation point? The provided argument shows only that every accumulation point of the set lies in the set, right?

Comment: @Chou Yes, to the second sentence. That is one of the characterizations of closed sets of the plane. The first sentence with question mark makes sense, the argument is not showing that. But we don't need to show that: The set $\{(0,0)\}$ is closed but $(0,0)$ is not an accumulation point of points in that set.